# Why do I need a class extension to make a method private?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've been reading a little bit about this and what I don't understand is why people adds class extensions to make a method private.

Wouldn't it suffice to just leave it out from the header file? 
It looks to me to be enough, but I might be missing a bigger point?

Comment: Until the most recent version of LLVM, the compiler did not search your entire implementation file for all of the method signatures. Therefore if you attempted to call `[self foo]` **above** your implementation of `- (void)foo` the compiler would yell at you for attempting to call an undeclared method. Also for organization's sake it's nice to have a class extension in your implementation file listing your private methods. It's also easier to read method documentation if it's all in one place.

Comment: Ironically, I just tweeted about this the other day:http://twitter.com/yar2050/status/249283047483117568. Also, very true what Jack Lawrence said, but you could get around it by ordering called methods above calling methods... a workaround that I have to fix in my code every time I see it :(

Comment: good question +1. you should accept answers on questions you have asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: now (as of Xcode 4.4, I think), you don't.  Reason: you don't need to forward declare methods.  Put your private methods in your .m file, and you're done.

Previously (Xcode 4.3 and older), you had to forward declare your methods before you could call them.  Because you already declared the class in the .h file, you can't declare it again in the .m file, so a class extension is the way to add methods to an already declared class.

**Edit:** as @Yar mentioned above (and below), a private method in a .m file that isn't declared would not be visible to subclasses of that class, meaning it would be impossible for that subclass to call or override that method.  Still, I'd be inclined to just not bother declaring it, unless/until you end up with a subclass that needs to override or call it.  For me this happens pretty infrequently.

Comment: Great +1 for putting it all together.

Answer (score 1):

It would be sufficient to leave it out of the header file, but then your subclasses don't know it's there, either. This means that you get a compiler error if you try to call these private methods. This is why you use an external file that is a class extension, and all subclasses import that extension **in the .m file.**

Obviously, this situation is not ideal because you get three files for each class, minimum, but the joy of Objective-C is about making LOTS of files and not worry about it. If you are scared to make files, you will end up with big classes, [which is an anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

One problem is naming the class extension file, since it's a category with no, um, category. I've been using a scheme like Blah4Subclasses, which is probably about as bad a suggestion as you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

the class continuation has nothing to do with access, wrt the translation. the objc language does not specify access for methods. so it's a relatively weak private. what people end up falling back on is the ability to hide method declarations in their implementation file.

the important point to take away is that the class continuation is generally only visible to your class (because it is often placed in the `*.m` file). this pattern *reduces* the likelihood of a private method's use because it is not visible to the client, or to the compiler (in translations other than the one which contains the class' `@implementation` in the typical structure).

also note that the class continuation is capable of a lot -- so it's a convenient place to store your private `@interface`; properties, ivars, methods.

lastly, it is also a habit from earlier days, because it was a more frequent necessity. not too long ago, the declaration was added so the compiler knew the object responded to a specific selector, and the signature of that selector. because clang parses the entire @implementation block these days, many people find they do not need the declarations in the class continuation because the compiler can match methods seen in the @implementation, regardless of order of declaration.

Comment: Great answer: comprehensive as always. Thanks. BTW, if it's a bad question, why answer it, and if it's not, why not upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add @private in your .h file.

Comment: Yes i can. Maybe my question wasn't quite accurate. See question in last paragraph.

Comment: Also @private doesn't apply to methods. Only properties. Also sometimes, if you're making a framework, you don't want your framework consumer to easily be aware that method X exists since it could be dangerous for them to call directly. (Which you would still be able to do, even if it's marked as private.)